# Array with the same multiple values

Tags: php, arrays

I coded this snippet:

```
$a = array('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O');

$rk = array_rand($a, 3);

$l = $a[$rk[0]].$a[$rk[1]].$a[$rk[2]];

if($l == 'OOO' || $l == 'XXX'){

   echo $l . 'Winner';

} else {

   echo = $l . 'Loser';

}
```

In the array you will notice multiples of the same values this is because three are chosen randomly and if matched you win (its a basic game).

My question is how can it be coded without having to add multiples of the same value in the array?

**Update:**
Answer to Yanick Rochon question

as it stands the array is:

```
$a = array('X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O');
```

is is possible somehow to have it as just

```
$a = array('X', 'O');
```

and still have 3 values returned?

Comment: Can you give an example of an "acceptable" array? Do you mean `array('X','X','X','O','O','O')` is not acceptable, but `array('X','X','X','A','B','C')` would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a basic rand:

```
<?php
$a = array('X', 'O', 'R');
$size = count($a)-1;

$l = $a[rand(0,$size)].$a[rand(0,$size)].$a[rand(0,$size)];

if($l == 'OOO' || $l == 'XXX'){
   echo $l . ' Winner';
} else {
   echo $l . ' Loser';
}
?>
```

Version with XXX or OOO or RRR win:

```
<?php
$a = array('X', 'O', 'R');
$size = count($a)-1;

$l = $a[rand(0,$size)].$a[rand(0,$size)].$a[rand(0,$size)];

if($l === 'OOO' || $l === 'XXX' || $l === 'RRR'){
   echo $l . ' Winner';
} else {
   echo $l . ' Loser';
}
?>
```

Comment: In testing I get wins and loses, I did however edit it to include if RRR also.

Answer (score 1):

To procedurally create an entire program, here is a code snippet. You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/41908e113fe3e3c5439a2ce93e8a130b590ca6da).

```
function randomArray($multiple, $length = 4) {
    if ($length <= $multiple) {
       throw new Exception('Length must be greater than multiple');
    }

    // define possible characters
    $possible = 'ABCEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 

    $value = str_repeat(substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1), $multiple);
    $i = strlen($value);

    // add random characters to $value until $length is reached
    while ($i < $length) { 

        // pick a random character from the possible ones
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);

        // we don't want this character if it's already in the string
        if (!strstr($value, $char)) { 
            $value .= $char;
            $i++;
        }

    }

    // done!
    $value = str_split($value);
    shuffle($value);

    return $value;
}

// return a random selection from the given array
// if $allowRepick is true, then the same array value may be picked multiple times
function arrayPick($arr, $count, $allowRepick = false) {
    $value = array();

    if ($allowRepick) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
            array_push($value, $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)]);
        }
    } else {
        shuffle($arr);

        $value = array_slice($arr, 0, $count);
    }

    return $value;
}


// generate an array with 4 values, from which 3 are the same
$values = randomArray(3, 4);

// pick any 3 distinct values from the array
$choices = arrayPick($values, 3, false);

// convert to strings
$valuesStr = implode('', $values);
$choicesStr = implode('', $choices);

echo 'Value  : ' . $valuesStr . "\n";
//echo 'Choice : ' . $choicesStr . "\n";

if (preg_match('/^(.)\1*$/', $choicesStr)) {
    echo $choicesStr . ' : Winner!';
} else {
    echo $choicesStr . ' : Loser!';
}
```

**Note** : the function `randomArray` will fail if `$length - $multiple > count($possible)`. For example, this call `randomArray(1, 27)` will fail, and the script will run indefinitely. Just so you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
$letter = false;
$winner = true;

foreach($rk as $key)
{
   if($letter === false) $letter = $a[$key];
   elseif($a[$key] != $letter) $winner = false;
}

if($winner) echo 'Winner';
else echo 'Loser';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = 3;  
$unique_vals = array('X','O');  
$a = array();  
foreach ($unique_vals as $val)  
{  
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $a[] = $val;
    }
}
```